# view facebook open graph custom objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I know that there is an object browser, but that doesn't seem to show me any of the objects I've created.  Is there another tool / method to view all objects created for a given type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually fairly simple once I stopped using facebooksharp and facebook# and just used a rest client or my own http request.

```
    var client = new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com");
    var request = new RestRequest("app/objects/app_name:object_type?access_token=" + AppToken);
    var response = client.Execute(request).Content;
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```